# ZF - How to render a view with its controller?

Tags: zend-framework, view, controller, render

I want to call another view from my view, but I need this new one to be processed with its controller, so I can have my SQL queries.

I am using `$this->render('new-view.phtml')` but this does not process the controller together, it returns only the view.

Anybody know how to do it? Thanks!

EDITED

Using $this->_forward(); i got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'RenderScript' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/;C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/dentallab/application/modules/default/views\helpers/' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\libraries\Zend_Framework_1\1.12.3\library\Zend\Loader\PluginLoader.php:412 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\libraries\Zend_Framework_1\1.12.3\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(1182): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('RenderScript') #1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\libraries\Zend_Framework_1\1.12.3\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(618): Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'renderScript') #2 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\libraries\Zend_Framework_1\1.12.3\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(344): Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('renderScript') #3 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\dentallab\application\modules\default\views\scripts\instituci in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\libraries\Zend_Framework_1\1.12.3\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php on line 336
```

Comment: Can't you just redirect/forward to the target controller?

Comment: I cant just redirect, need it to be 'included' in my main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 $this->_forward($action, $controller);
```

as thom suggested if you want to use you controller and view script from another view script .

Comment: _forward() also accepts "module" incase you need to do that ->_forward("view", "user", "cms");